# Setup a secondary SSH/SFTP user with limited directory access

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I am trying to create a new secondary user that has access to SFTP files and SSH access to a specific directory.

I have the SFTP work, but when I try to login via SSH, I get the following error: Write failed: Broken pipe

The root user uses a public/private key, but I want the secondary user to use a password.

Here is what I have so far:

```
useradd test
passwd test
usermod -G www-data test
usermod -d /usr/share/nginx/html test
chown test:www-data /usr/share/nginx/html
```

As for additions to my sshd_config:

```
AllowUsers test

Match User test
        ChrootDirectory /usr/share/nginx/html
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

All I have left to do is to get the test user to be able access the CLI in their home directory to run composer and artisan commands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that you have wrong permissions on ChrootDirectory

This is quote from `man sshd_config`

> All components of the pathname must be root-owned directories that are not writable by any other user or group.

Also check `/var/log/auth.log` on server, there you will see a error message.